# Mysterious `The "modules" key in the @Module() decorator is deprecated`

Tags: nestjs

Running a nestjs application and the console shows:

```
WARNING!!
The "modules" key in the @Module() decorator is deprecated and will be removed within next major release. Use the "imports" key instead.
```

My modules are declared like :

```
@Module({
    imports: [UserModule],
    providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
    controllers: [AuthController]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

I also executed "find in path" for the word `modules` to ensure there is no `modules` in my code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue with older versions of NestJs. Upgrading package.json helped.
Make sure that you use up-to-date versions ^5.0.0 for all @nestjs/* packages.